# Repeating audio noise loop when no music or audio playing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, audacity

When I am not playing music or watching videos on my Ubuntu 18.04 install, there is a constant repeating audio loop thing that plays out of the right side of my headphones (the issue is not with my headphones, it happens with any headphones/earphones). The sound is similar to that which is made by a vinyl record player when the needle is first placed on the record. Now imagine that repeating every 2 seconds, out of only one ear.

Heres a link to what that vinyl thing sounds like: 
https://youtu.be/CclOy8IrDyQ?t=26

If I watch a video or play some music it stops. When I stop the music, it will start after about 10-15 seconds of silence.

Another way to stop it is to install PulseAudio Volume Control and to keep it open at all times. This is what I have been using to prevent myself from going insane. The noise will start again 10-15 seconds after PulseAudio is closed.

I've had this problem for a while, but I think it started when I was playing around with Audacity and audio recording with a microphone. I had probably installed some things which caused it to begin.

However, I have since done a clean reinstall of Ubuntu 18.04, and I still have the problem.

Help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same problem on Fedora 33 after switching from a headphone to a jack cable branched on a stereo amplifier. Honestly I don't know why it happened now or if this is related at all to the hardware output but here is how I solved it :

By killing pulseaudio and relaunching it in verbose mode ( `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -v` ), the following information stuck out :

```
[pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink alsa_output.pci-0000_0b_00.3.analog-stereo idle for too long, suspending ...
```

Now I remember having experienced something similar in the past, only it was a loud glitching noise popping when an audio source went idle or was restored. The solution is to keep the idle audio source from suspending. In `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, comment out the `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` instruction :

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Judging from what I can read online and what I experienced, it's an old problem, sometimes funnily described as a "machine gun" sound. This question is month old now, and you probably solved it by yourself, but hopefully It will spare a headache to someone else in the future

Source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#guvcview

Comment: Will this Fedora solution work with Ubuntu?

Comment: In the meantime I had to create an install of Ubuntu 18.04. I met the exact same problem and luckily fixed it using this very method.

Additional unrelated details : The "beeping" noise persists when I suspend the machine. If I power on the machine, the beep will start early in the boot and only stops  when I log into the Gnome user session.

Comment: This solved it twice now for me. Thanks! Ubuntu 20.04, two different computers.