# Ubuntu 20.04 headphone buzzing

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones

I've been having this issue where I only hear buzzing when I plug in my headset (But the sound plays normally when I unplug). I've tried at least 10 fixes I've googled including [Ubuntu 20.04 - After last update, speakers are buzzing unless I open the sound settings window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241617/ubuntu-20-04-after-last-update-speakers-are-buzzing-unless-i-open-the-sound-s) and none of them seems to work.

It'd be great if someone knows how to fix this.